# LIMIT 1 on a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How could I limit the JOIN to only show once for every player? `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name 
LIMIT 10
```

And perhaps find the most common value of lasthit or mostdamage and order by that

Comment: Does DISTINCT work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name 
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. No need for parenthesis there.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pd ON pd.lasthit = p.name 
OR pd.mostdamage = p.name 
GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: The use of both distinct and group by is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to first downsize the original table you are joining against, otherwise the answers by the other people are more accurate:

```
SELECT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM player_frags pd
            GROUP BY pd.lasthit, pd.mostdamage) AS newpd ON newpd.lasthit = p.name OR
                                                            newpd.mostdamage = p.name 
LIMIT 10
```